# Не создается файл. java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: android, файлы

В манифесте разрешения указал. Не пойму какого permission не хватает. Может что с путями не так?

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);
    dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    textViewDir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDir);
    textViewDir.setText(dirPath);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            File file = new File(dirPath + "/" + editText.getText().toString());
            if (isExterntalStorageWritetable()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.filesave) + dirPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error) + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, стектрейс ошибки, если она есть. И функцию `isExterntalStorageWritetable`. Что она делает?

Comment: `В манифесте разрешения указал` – а какие?

Comment: И вообще говоря, [`Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace.`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

Comment: на каком андроиде тестируете?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы тестирует на 6 андроиде. Там уже используется runtime pernission. Советую прочитать статью на хабре, если не знаете что это

Comment: Cпасибо! Реализовал requestPermissions и все заработало